# Why my UIActivityIndicator goes in minus x coordinate in UIButton as a subview

Tags: iphone, ios, layout, uiview, subview

I have the following code in

```
- (void) loadView {
    self.okButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    CGFloat w = 20;
    self.indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, w, w)];
    indicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    self.indicator.center = self.okButton.center;
    [self.okButton addSubview:indicator];
    indicator.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
}
```

okButton is added in a complex view hierarchy. I want the indicator place properly in okButton. But its in loadview and in viewDidLoad, the frames are giving the following values,

```
<UIButton: 0x210620a0; frame = (10 121; 300 50); opaque = NO; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x21061560>>, 
<UIActivityIndicatorView: 0x21062540; frame = (-0.5 15; 20 20); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x21062640>>
```

Why the indicator's x goes from 5 to -0.5 ?

Edit:
I should remove one line, calculate position of indicator as follows,

```
//    self.indicator.center = self.okButton.center;
CGFloat size = 20, y = (self.okButton.frame.size.height - size)/2;
self.indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, y, size, size)];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is at this line :

```
self.indicator.center = self.okButton.center;
```

Indicator is a subview of okButton but you set coordinates with x and y values relatives to superview. You should use width/2 and height/2 to get center from inside a view.

Comment: Thanks. I did not notice the center issue.